# Property of a group modulo $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

If I have the group $H/\mathbb{Z}$  with $H$ finitely presented and $H/\mathbb{Z}$ finite. Is then $H/\mathbb{Z}$ always cyclic?

Comment: How is $\mathbb Z$ a subgroup of $H$? Perhaps you mean $Z(H)$, the center of $H$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a noncyclic finite abelian group and consider $H=\mathbb{Z}\oplus G$.